# use composite key within another composite key (@MapsId("id_1, id_2, id_3"))?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have a **composite_id_a (id_1, id_2, id_3)** in **class_a** and want to use **composite_id_a** in **class_b** as part of its own **composite_id_b**.

The **class_b** has **composite_id_a** as part of its primary key and is also its foreign key.

**How should I map the foreign key in class_b?**

class_b:

```
public class B{

@EmbeddedId
private CompositeId_B composite_id_b;

// This does not work: I cannot use more properties in @MapsId
@MapsId("id_1, id_2, id_3")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_1", referencedColumnName="ID_1"),
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_2", referencedColumnName="ID_2"),
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_3", referencedColumnName="ID_3")})
private A class_a;
}
```

composite id of class B:

```
@Embeddable
public class Id_B{

@Column(name = "ID_1")
private Integer id_1;

@Column(name = "ID_2")
private Integer id_2;

@Column(name = "ID_3")
private Integer id_3;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
}
```

composite id of class A:

```
@Embeddable
public class Id_A{

@Column(name = "ID_1")
private Integer id_1;

@Column(name = "ID_2")
private Integer id_2;

@Column(name = "ID_3")
private Integer id_3;
}
```

class_a:

```
public class A{

@EmbeddedId
private ID_A id_a;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_1", referencedColumnName="ID_1"),
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_2", referencedColumnName="ID_2"),
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_3", referencedColumnName="ID_3")})
private Set<B> b = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**I cannot use something like this, as the following error is thrown:**

```
public class B{

@EmbeddedId
private CompositeId_B composite_id_b;

// This does not work: I cannot use more properties in @MapsId
@MapsId("composite_id_a")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_1", referencedColumnName="ID_1"),
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_2", referencedColumnName="ID_2"),
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_3", referencedColumnName="ID_3")})
private A class_a;
}
```

another version of composite id of class B (does not work):

```
@Embeddable
public class Id_B{

@EmbeddedId
private CompositeId_A composite_id_a;

@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
}


13:55:46,010 ERROR [org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure:42] HCANN000002: An assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate): org.hibernate.annotations.common.AssertionFailure: Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy: entity.CompositeId_B
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.getMappedSuperclassOrNull(BinderHelper.java:811)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the JPA spec calls a "derived identity". Speculating on the mishmash : ) of code you provide, you should define your classes slightly differently:

```
@Embeddable
public class Id_A implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "ID_1")
    private Integer id_1;

    @Column(name = "ID_2")
    private Integer id_2;

    @Column(name = "ID_3")
    private Integer id_3;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Id_A id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<B> bSet = new HashSet<>();
}

@Embeddable
public class Id_B implements Serializable {
    Id_A aId;   // corresponds to PK type of A

    String name;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @EmbeddedId
    private Id_B id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_1", referencedColumnName="ID_1"),
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_2", referencedColumnName="ID_2"),
        @JoinColumn(name="ID_3", referencedColumnName="ID_3")})
    @MapsId("aId")
    private A a;
}
```

Note the `@MapsId` annotation on `B.a` and the `OneToMany.mappedBy` setting on `A.bSet`.

Also, I believe the one Hibernate error you document ("Declaring class is not found in the inheritance state hierarchy") is the result of having an `@EmbeddedId` annotation inside an `@Embeddable`.

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the JPA 2.1 spec in section 2.4.1.